# Disable enter fullscreen mode automatically based on the device's width in vidstack react player

Tags: reactjs, video-player, vidstack-player

I am using this [player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vidstack/react) in one of my React projects. I am showing the video player in a modal. So when the screen width of the device is below 1024px then I want the fullscreen mode should not apply.

I read the [official documentation](https://www.vidstack.io/docs/player) but didn't get the official way to disable entering fullscreen mode automatically for a specific device's width.

```
<MediaPlayer
    className="w-full h-[540px] bg-slate-200 text-white font-sans overflow-hidden rounded-md ring-media-focus data-[focus]:ring-4"
    title={title}
    src={src}
    crossorigin
    ref={player}
    autoplay
>
    <MediaProvider>
    <Poster
        className="absolute inset-0 block h-full w-full rounded-md opacity-0 transition-opacity data-[visible]:opacity-100 object-cover"
        src={thumbnail_url}
        alt={title || ""}
    />
    </MediaProvider>

    <VideoLayout />
</MediaPlayer>
```

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with the author of the player [Rahim Alwer](https://github.com/mihar-22) there is a property available for the `MediaPlayer` component named `playsinline`

so this is what I did

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const VideoPlayer: React.FunctionComponent<VideoPlayerProps> = ({ src, title, thumbnail_url }) => {
  let player = useRef<MediaPlayerInstance>(null);
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

  useEffect(() => {
    function reportWindowSize() {
      setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
    }
    // Trigger this function on resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize)
    //  Cleanup for componentWillUnmount
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize)
  }, [])

  return (
    <MediaPlayer 
      playsinline={windowWidth >= 1024}
    >
      ...
    </MediaPlayer>
  )

}
```

PS:- There was a small bug with it too that got resolved today. so we should be on the latest version(1.5.3).